How to resolve 'Upgrade to Lodash version 4.17.12 or later' - Lodash vulnerability
We've found Lodash vulnerability in our app 'Lodash < 4.17.12 Prototype Pollution'
and the solution is 'Upgrade to Lodash version 4.17.12 or later.'
but can't find any reference of Lodash in our code.
Can you please advise we can find it how we can upgrade the version ?
Thanks
